# PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column photos.attachable_type does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

So, I've followed [this tutorial](http://lucapette.com/rails/multiple-files-upload-with-carrierwave-and-nested_form/) but swap @article with current_user or (my user model), and :attachments with :photos or my Photo model.

One thing i'll say which might help is I'm not sure why he references attachable? Shouldn't he be referencing article? or in my case User?

I'm getting this error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column photos.attachable_type does not exist
LINE 1: ..."photos"  WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos"  WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2
```

my form snippet:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">                                                                                                            
                  <%= nested_form_for current_user, :html=>{:multipart => true } do |f| %>                                                                    
                    <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p|  %>                                                                                                       
                    <p>                                                                                                                                       
                    <%= p.label :file %><br />                                                                                                               
                    <%= p.file_field :file %>                                                                                                                
                    </p>                                                                                                                                      
                    <%= p.link_to_remove "Remove this attachment" %>                                                                                          
                    <% end %>                                                                                                                                 
                    <%= f.link_to_add "Add attachment", :photos %>                                                                                            
                    <p><%= f.submit %></p>                                                                                                                    
                    <% end %>                                                                                                                                 
                  </div>
```

user.rb snippet

```
has_many :photos, as: :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

photos.rb full

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :file

  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true

  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Photo model belongs_to `:attachable` as a polymorphic association, which means it needs two columns - `:attachable_type` (a string) and `:attachable_id` (an integer). So for example if User ID #1 has a photo, the photo's attachable_type would be 'User' and attachable_id would be 1.

You'll need to create a migration to add these fields to your Photo model if you haven't already. You can do this by (in a migration) doing:

```
change_table :photos do |t|
  t.references :attachable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: hey, would you happen to have a clue as to why when I click Add Attachment it's returning javascript.void(0) in the bottom of my browser? With no pop up to upload images?

Comment: without seeing the code you're running to add an attachment? no.

Comment: using the nested_forms gem, let me see if I can find the code for you.

Comment: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/blob/master/lib/nested_form/builder_mixin.rb there's the link_to_add code the I used?

Comment: I have pretty much the same thing, only I did add this migration, can see the column in my schema, though still not working.